# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, unexpected-token

I'm a beginner in React Native trying to test out TouchableOpacity. I keep getting this error code 'Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (16:4)'

The issue seems to be at the opening TouchableOpacity tag.

I've already tried putting fragments around it but it didn't work does anyone know how I fix this??

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react- 
   native';


const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (

  <View>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Sup boiz</Text>
    <Button
      onPress={() => console.log('Button pressed')} 
      title="Go to components demo"
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log('List Pressed')>
        <Text>Go to List demo</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code, that's probably the issue

Comment: You're missing the closing curly brace in your `onPress` call in the TouchableOpacity tag.

Comment: bruh, use a linter.

Comment: damn i didnt even see that thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log('List Pressed')}>
        <Text>Go to List demo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Simple syntax error. It should be `onPress={ () => console.log('List Pressed')}`

You missed `}`